# How to make custom GridView in android

Tags: android, gridview

I want to create a grid view but the default grid view is not useful.

I want to create the same grid view as this image:

[image]

Here is my Grid view:

```
<GridView
            android:id="@+id/list_product_grid"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:listitem="@layout/products_page_grid_view"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:verticalSpacing="2dp"/>
```

And my snapshot:

[image]

Comment: you can manage your layout by frame layout for XML and using base recylerview adapter class ......

Comment: Create custom xml for your row and set in grid adapter

Answer (score 0):

To do that you need to build your custom list / grid view using a Fragment list, and use custom a ListAdapter / ListItem for it as shown in this tutorial about [List Fragments In Android Studio](https://www.airpair.com/android/list-fragment-android-studio#6-testing-our-list-fragment).

Comment: It'd be even more helpful if you edited your answer to include the relevant parts of the link *in the answer*. That will guard against link rot, or the site being hacked, etc.